# SSRS How to tell if a dataset associated with a Tablix has any data

Tags: ssrs-2012

Working in Visual Studio 2015 with SSRS .rdlc files.
We have a subreport consisting of a TextBox and a Tablix.  We want to make the visibility of the textbox dependent on whether the tablix is displaying any data.
I believe we can reference the tablix by its name in an expression:
ReportItems!Tablix1

but how can the textbox know if the tablix is empty or not?

Thanks for any insights....
[edited for clarity]

Answer (score 2):

You could just count the dataset rows, so set the `Hidden` property something like

```
= IIF(CountRows("yourDatasetName") =0, True, False)
```

**Note** Make sure you include the quotes and the dataset name IS case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I realized that the subreport is in a group, so while the dataset has rows, the tablix in the subreport might not...  Is there a way (similar to CountRows("DatasetName") to find out if a tablix has any data?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can navigate to subreport properties, others may know how to though. The only other way might be to add some summary data to your main reports dataset that will indicate if the subreport will contain data or not. Your circumstances may mean that's not possible but that's all I can think of at ht moment.